# Is using session to identify roles a good approach?

Tags: asp.net, session

I've recently started learning ASP.NET, and I was also learning about Membership and role management. It was used to manage roles but I wanted to know if using session to identify roles is a good approach?

My assignment website has 2 roles in it (Customer, Artist) and I am currently using a session to identify who is who and based on the session role I allow access to certain pages. So during page_load of gallery for example, I check if session role is artist and deny access (redirect them to their own profile, etc).

I was hoping someone could clarify if this approach is safe (Im not sure how to word it), or should I use ASP's own membership management to accomplish this.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I have previously developed big commercial apps and I would like to highlight that I also used session to identify user-type apart from other things.
I had not just 2 but more user types, the advantage of using session this way is that the user-type is same for him and this SHOULD be as it is throughout his usage.

Hence, it is OK to bind user role to session as it will remain same throughout application until log-out.